# InternalsVisibleTo except for a few classes

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-construction, internalsvisibleto

I applied `InternalsVisibleTo` to one of my projects in order for its internals to be visible for test projects. However, (this is weird I know) I need to mark a few internal classes so that they won't be visible to the projects which is indicated through `InternalsVisibleTo`.

Is there any attribute I can apply for this that the compiler is aware of?

Comment: Make the class private instead?

Comment: @RJLohan Then, other classes cannot use it. This is the whole point of internal access modifier.

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible. The alternative is to move those classes into their own assembly.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead yep I thought about that but I don't really wanna do that either :s

Comment: Since InternalsVisibleTo can only be used at the assembly level, and internal is the only way to make a class public except for other assemblies, I don't think it's possible. Only way is moving those types. Think it over, maybe these types make sense living in a separate assembly.

Comment: @AndersonSilva thanks! I ended up separating the test projects so that I won't reference both projects as I was getting compile errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anderson Silva is correct.  There is no way to do this.  You should consider moving the types to a new assembly.  Alternatively, you could think about applying the `[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]` attribute to hide the types from IntelliSense, although if the user knows about them, the code will compile.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I ended up separating the test projects.